# "Discovering Python Interpreters" taking Infinite time in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am new to Ubuntu, as well as to python.
( This problem has started just recently until now everything was fine.)
Whenever I am trying to start my VS Code to learn Django, the VS Code is showing the following issue for an infinite time

[image]

i.e., it is not discovering Python interpreters.
The problem seems to be in the Python Extension which I am using.
I tried to Uninstall it and then reinstall it. But it turned out to be of no use.
I even tried to uninstall and reinstall vscode from my ubuntu (20.04) system itself. But vs code started from exactly where I left, with no change.
I even tried to change the python interpreter path from the command palate, but it also didn't work.
[image]

I could find something relatable [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135210), but I couldn't understand/follow them.
Help from someone's side would be appreciated.

Comment: vscode doesnt always know which interpreter you want to use. Could be that its already configured to look in some place but there is nothing. Maybe because you created a venv and removed it. Just select one interpreter from the list.

Comment: based on the github issue you linked, it seems like that thread got locked as offtopic because it's a *bug* with the extension currently.

Comment: Have you tried to create a virtual environment? And could you provide the outputs in OUTPUT -> Python

Comment: @Steven-MSFT the problem lies in the extension. Python naturally works fine on VSCode, but the extension is not able to find the interpreter I guess

Comment: Have you tried the age old "turn the computer off and on again" strategy? Worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I've recently started experiencing the same problem with VS Code (latest version), albeit on Windows 10. I'm using Python 3.10.4 from python.org, the latest Microsoft Python extension, and a virtual environment for the workspace in which I do Python development. The option to select the interpreter is dysfunctional - it doesn't offer an interpreter to select. The workaround I found is to terminate and restart VS Code until it discovers the Python interpreter in the virtual environment. Frustrating, but it works, without having to uninstall and reinstall everything (yes, I unsuccessfully tried that too).

Answer (score 2):

Try Disabling and uninstalling like extensions. There might be a conflict of some sort.

So, go to vscode Extensions > click the [...] button > show running extensions.

if the Python extension is running alongside pylint and pylance, then that might be where your problem stems from. Since Python contains pylance, and maybe pylint too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the Ms Python Extension which I am using so I disabled the `Microsoft python extension`.

Answer (score 0):

You can open vscode successfully, but find python interperter forever. It suggests that the python extension get stuck.

So, I uninstall all python extensions in vscode. And reopen vscode, reinstall those python extension.

The extensions I keep are shown below:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Mine method is quite simple, just close the vs code for a minute, restart it, and run a simple code again, like 1 +1, wait the Interpreter to connect, my problem settled.

Comment: doesn't work for me. I have had left the system for days. still the problem exists

Comment: Do we all agree in saying that VS Code could be greatly improved?

Comment: Doesn't work for me.